# Spring data JPA entities and DTO for ActiveMQ

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, activemq-classic, dto

I need to transfer some data from one node of my application to another. So the question is  - can I fetch for example User entity with help of Spring Data/JPA an put it to session.createObjectMessage(User) or do I need to create a separated UserDTO, populate it with data from User object and send ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sure, if you make the entity implement Serializable.

However, I would be very careful about sending entities around to different instances by any means. It's usually better to keep the Entity pretty tight to the database in terms of optimizations etc. You may want to be able to tweak how data is loaded (lazy/eager etc) and other DB centric matters without worrying about the state of your transfered object.

Creating a DTO shouldn't be that much work now to save you some headaches in the future.

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't use Java serialisation to exchange data between applications as brings strong coupling between applications (you need to have the same .class files in both applications). It's not that hard to serialize in JSON with Jackson or in XML with JAXB, XStream... Moreover from a monitoring point of view, it's better because a human can read the messages stored in ActiveMQ...

Comment: This was however between instances of the same application - which is not between applications.

Comment: On a side note, don't use things like @elementcollection when you serialize entities. JPA/hibernate will convert the collection to an internal type which is serializable but likely not available on the receiver of the serialized data. Took me quite long to figure out.